# Lookahead regex in Oracle SQL - strip zeros after underscore

Tags: regex, oracle, regex-lookarounds

I've used the following regex to strip all Zeros following an underscore: `(?<=_)0+` (in Java) or `/(?<=_)0+/` (in php).

E.g. `Serial_Number_000000222` -> `Serial_Number_222`

This ["lookaroud" syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) doesn't appear to work in [Oracle](https://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9411765). Can anyone suggest an alternative?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
result := REGEXP_REPLACE(subject, '_0+', '_', 1, 0, 'c');
```

This replaces the underscore, followed by one or more zeroes, with the underscore itself.